# TYPO3 website doesn't work after changing db

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I want to make a copy of my TYPO3 CMS 6.2.18 website - what I did so far:

1. Copied the entire website folder (including the TYPO3 installation)
2. Copied the entire database (with a new name)
3. Created a new db user for the copied db
4. Adjusted the file `/typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php` accordingly to the new DB+User

Now I'm receiving following errors when calling different urls of my copied TYPO3 website:

When I try calling the "Upgrade Wizard" from inside the install tool /typo3/install (which is the only page that currently works):

```
#1: PHP Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /var/www/vhosts/<my-domain>/typo3/sysext/install/Classes/Service/SqlSchemaMigrationService.php line 409
```

When I call `<my-domain>/typo3`

```
 #1: PHP Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /var/www/vhosts/<my-domain>/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Utility/BackendUtility.php line 3022
4 count(NULL)
...
/var/www/vhosts/<my-domain>/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Utility/BackendUtility.php:
03020:   $signals = array();
03021:   $modData = $GLOBALS['BE_USER']->getModuleData('TYPO3\\CMS\\Backend\\Utility\\BackendUtility::getUpdateSignal', 'ses');
03022:   if (!count($modData)) {
03023:    return '';
03024:   }
```

When I call `<my-domain>`

```
#1: PHP Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /var/www/vhosts/<my-domain>/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Database/PreparedStatement.php line 582
...after calling... 
TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\PreparedStatement::convertNamedPlaceholdersToQuestionMarks("SELECT * FROM fe_session_data WHERE hash = :hash", array, array)
```

What's interesting to me:
After copying the website the copy worked, only after referencing it to the copied db it showed these errors.

Anyone an idea what I could do / be looking for?
I tried deleting all cache, all tables shown in the "Cleanup" part of the install tool and all files in the typoe3temp folder already.

Comment: Do you have both set up on the same server? All are the PHP warning, probably this only means you have different PHP version on the server. Does this make sense?

Comment: I have them on the same server, but I can change the php version of each of my TYPO3 pages individually - so thanks for the hint - I will check if they're the same.

Comment: are you sure your new user has access to the copied DB? Does the Install-Tool report any errors or warnings?

Comment: @GhanshyamBhava it was indeed the php-version! Thank you! Feel free to post your comment as an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: Cool, Keep coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as I have said in the comment. Probably the issue with PHP version, because of all the mentioned errors (warning actually ;) ) reflect the incompatible PHP code.

The solution is pretty easy, switch your PHP version according to TYPO3's need :)